# Dockerfile's env does not see other environment variables?

Tags: docker

In my Dockerfile I go over to user postgres. Anyway, the environment variable HOME equals /var/lib/pgsql. Now I would like to create another environment variable, PGDATA, which should be $HOME/data. But somehow I cannot do in in the Dockerfile. I did:

```
user postgres
run env           # HOME=/var/lib/pgsql
env PGDATA=$HOME/data         
run env           # PGDATA=/data
```

So when I build the image, $HOME is empty on the 3rd line. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Environment variable references in Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement) get expanded by Docker before they're passed on to the shell.  In particular, if an `ENV` statement includes any sort of `$variable` reference, only previous `ENV` and `ARG` statements are visible to it.  (Implicit changes of, say, `$HOME` via a `USER` directive aren't directly visible to the Dockerfile.)

In practice, since you control the entire runtime environment of the Docker image, you can easily enough specify a fixed data directory and hard-code its location later on.  The layout of the Docker filesystem space doesn't especially need to be configurable.